# Запись битов в файл C++

Tags: c++

Имеется vector<bool>. Как я могу записать его значинеия в байт, а затем записать этот байт в файл?

Comment: если не известно, что именно в этом векторе хранится, то ответ один - делать сериализацию

Comment: @KoVadim , Что вы подразумеваете под "неизветсно"?

Comment: то, что в угловых скобках написано. Если там char или int - это одно дело. А если там std::string - это совсем другое

Comment: @KoVadim , почему-то не отобразило, что vector<bool>

Comment: о, vector<bool>  - это вообще отдельный случай. Прямо совсем отдельный

Comment: @KoVadim, это всё, конечно, хорошо. Но что делать-то?

Comment: Значени**я** или отдельное значени**е**? Весь вектор или отдельные его значения? В бинарный файл или в текстовый? Каждый `bool` в отдельный байт или по 8 `bool`ов в байт? Уточните вопрос...

Comment: @Harry, значения

Comment: Если по одному - просто циклом читайте в байт и пишите его, если по 8 - то, увы, насколько я помню, стандарт не предоставляет доступ к лежащему в основе массиву...

Comment: @Harry, а как писать по одному?

Comment: если есть возможность заменить vector<bool> на bitset, тогда все может быть сильно проще. Если там битов до 64, там прям есть (ullong)[https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ullong], который можно просто взять и сохранить. Правда, если битов меньше, то лучше и размер сохранить.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я бы делал так - если по одному...

Не компилирую, просто набросок!

```
vector<bool> v;
...
size_t sz = v.size();
file.write((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
for(size_t i = 0; i <= sz; ++i)
{
    unsigned char c = v[i];
    file.write((char*)&c,sizeof(c));
}
```

Читал бы - сначала размер, потом соответствующее число байт читать и вносить в вектор.

Comment: по байту на бит... возможно, но лучше пусть все таки автор вопроса уточнит свое задание

Comment: @KoVadim Да, не спорю. Но это ответ на его уточненный вопрос - **а как писать по одному?**  - я для того и задавал уточняющие вопросы в комментариях. Быстрого *и переносимого* решения все равно нет, а память сейчас уже не такая дорогая, особенно дисковая :) Но, конечно, можно и собирать в `bitset` и писать.

Comment: Как я понимаю, в данном случае предпочтительнее использовать bitset?

Comment: Не столько предпочтительнее, сколько удобнее :)

Comment: А можно пример использования для данного случая?

Comment: Просто - если до 64 бит - воспользоваться функцией [`to_ullong`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ullong) и превратить в `unsigned long long`, каковой и записать в файл.